# Combining several arrays into a binned array (performance)

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7

I have a set (15-25) arrays in the `[(x,y),(x,y),..]` form (around 250k coordinate-pairs per array) which I am attempting to average by binning them (into **65.000** bins!!). I have attempted several options but so far the performance of all options has been sub-optimal and I was wondering if there are more efficient ways of doing this.

**My first method** (*This method uses binary search, this is also the best performance that I have achieved so far, averaging at a little over 1 minute per set of arrays.*)

```
def findNearest(self,array,value):
    if value >= array[0][0] and value <= array[-1][0]:
        diff = 1
        # First Pass
        a = 0
        b = len(array)
        while a < b:
            mid = (a+b)//2
            if array[mid][0] > value:
                b = mid
            else:
                a = mid+1
        if array[a][0] - value < diff:
            diff = array[a][0] - value
            index = a
        # Second Pass
        a = 0
        b = len(array)
        while a < b:
            mid = (a+b)//2
            if array[mid][0] < value:
                a=mid+1
            else:
                b=mid
        if array[a][0] - value < diff:
            diff = array[a][0] - value
            index = a
        return a    

# Section of another function that performs the summing
combinedSpectra = numpy.zeros(shape=(arraySize,2))
for index, i in enumerate(combinedSpectra):
    i[0] = ... # This generates the x-coordinates of the numpy array
for i in arraySet:
    for j in i:
        combinedSpectra[self.findNearest(combinedSpectra,float(j[0]))][1] += float(j[1])
```

**My second method** (*This method uses a concatenated list of all arrays, sorting them on x-coordinates and using the order of the x-coordinates to keep a as limited as possible double for loop. This method is however far slower than the first method and serves mostly as an illustration of alternatives that I have tried.*)

```
fullSet = []
for i in arraySet:
    for j in i:
        fullSet.append(j)
fullSet.sort(key = lambda tup: tup[0])
combinedSpectra = numpy.zeros(shape=(arraySize,2))
for index, i in enumerate(combinedSpectra):
    i[0] = ... # This generates the x-coordinates of the numpy array
for index1, i in enumerate(combinedSpectra[:-2]):
    for index2, j in enumerate(fullSet):
        if float(j[0]) >= float(combinedSpectra[index1+1][0]):
            break
        else:
            combinedSpectra[index1][1] += float(j[1])
```

**Third method** (*This method combines a binary search with a full set. This method takes just under 1 minute as well, therefore being slightly better than method 1.*)

```
fullSet = []
for i in array[lowTime:highTime]:
    for j in i[1]:
        fullSet.append(j)
fullSet.sort(key = lambda tup: tup[0])
for i in fullSet:
    try:
        combinedSpectra[self.findNearest(combinedSpectra,float(i[0]))][1] += float(i[1])
    else:
        pass
```

**Fourth Method** (*Using numpy.digitize as suggested by Simons Gibbons. This method also takes a bit over 1 minute (1m15s on average) in total.*)

```
combinedSpectra = numpy.zeros(shape=(arraySize,2))
bins = []
for index, i in enumerate(combinedSpectra):
    i[0] = float(LOW_MZ) + index*(float(1)/float(SUM_SPECTRUM_RESOLUTION))
    bins.append(float(LOW_MZ) + index*(float(1)/float(SUM_SPECTRUM_RESOLUTION)))
fullSet = []
mz = []
for i in arraySet:
    for j in i[1]:
        fullSet.append(j)
        mz.append(j[0])
fullSet.sort(key = lambda tup: tup[0])
mz.sort()
mzArray = numpy.asarray(mz)
binsArray = numpy.asarray(bins)
test = numpy.digitize(mzArray,bins)
for index, i in enumerate(fullSet):
    combinedSpectra[test[index]-1][1]] += i[1]
```

The issue that I am having is that this step is critical for the performance of the entire program, therefore I am searching for alternate methods to try with my data to see which offers the best performance.

**PS: Some notes about the data that I have in my arrays (to prevent confusion):**

1. The input arrays are of differing length
2. The input arrays have (therefore) differing x-coordinates

Comment: It looks like you're reinventing the [k-d tree datastructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using numpy already I'd suggest converting your input data set to a numpy array (using [`np.asarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html)) and then using [`np.digitize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) to do the binning.

Whilst this still does a binary search behind the scenes it will do this in fast compiled c code!

In a quick test I've done this will process an array of 250k points in less than half a second.

---

If your bins in `x` are monotonically increasing you can instead use [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) which should do the same thing as `np.digitize` only faster (digitize can fall back to a slow linear search sometimes)

to use this replace your call to digitize in your method 4 to be

```
numpy.searchsorted(bins, mzArray)
```

Comment: I will try those functions and report back.

Comment: `np.digitize` returns an array containing the indices, I would have to then still iterate over the returned array and add the y-value to the binned array, correct?

Comment: Yes exactly, although that shouldn't be a particularly time consuming step.

Comment: I have tested your suggestion, the actual line `test = numpy.digitize(mzArray,bins)` takes about 1 minute. I might have to add the number of bins (65.000) to the original question as that seems the be the cause of the delay?

Comment: That will make a big difference, I've added an extra part to my answer with another suggestion, (it should be a pretty easy change to the code you already have)

Comment: `np.searchsorted` is indeed the answer it seems, it managed to do the entire binning within 10 seconds on average. I am so curious regarding that function now that I might dig into the underlying C code of it.